# Error when input contains letters in Python

Tags: python

I have encountered a problem with eval(input(...)), it gives me an error when I input letters.

When I use instead this:

> first_input = km

It works perfectly fine. But I want to make user to input letters.

I found similar answers to my question, but they all relate to Python 2 and tell to use raw_input, but it doesn't work for me, however. Most likely because my Python version is 3.5.1.

Here is some part of my code:

```
    ...        

first_unit = eval(input("Enter the units for the first value (cm, m or km): "))

# convert units into m
if first_unit is 'cm':
   first_input = first_input / 100
elif first_unit is 'km':
   first_input = first_input * 1000
else:
   first_input = first_input

   ...
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? Why are you using `is` instead of `==` ?

Comment: `is` compares references, `==` compares values.  They often give the same result, but also often don't.

Comment: Please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DO NOT USE `eval`!!!**

In order to obtain an input from the user you simply call `input`. It returns a string already.

Secondly: **do not compare objects using `is`!** Use `==`:

```
first_unit = input("Enter the units for the first value (cm, m or km): ")

# convert units into m
if first_unit == 'cm':
   first_input = first_input / 100
elif first_unit == 'km':
   first_input = first_input * 1000
else:
   first_input = first_input
```

The `is` operator compares identities not values.

Note: to obtain a number from the user you should use either `int(input(..))` or `float(input(..))` depending on whether it is an integer or decimal.

Comment: Code runs perfectly now. I will keep in mind not to repeat these mistakes again in the future.